# pymysql-Can I manage and change the form of the results of my query?

Tags: python, pymysql

My question is pretty simple and I will explain to you what I mean.Lets say I have a random code like this:

```
sql_query="select first_name,age from random_table
cur.execute(sql_query)
results=cur.fetchall()
nested_tuple_list=[("genre","actor","tainies")]
for result in results:
    nested_tuple_list.append(result) 
nested_tuple_list=tuple(nested_tuple_list)
return(nested_tuple_list)
```

And this gives as a result something like this:

```
name    | age
stef    | 15
stef    | 16
stef    | 17
stef    | 18
jim     | 15
jim     | 16
jim     | 17
pan     | 15
pan     | 16
pan     | 17
tom     | 15
tom     | 16
tom     | 17
```

My function is something like this def names(n) so depending on the n I get I want to get N guys with the same first_name.Example n=1:

```
name    | age               
stef    | 15
jim     | 15
pan     | 15
tom     | 15
```

or

```
name    | age               
stef    | 16
jim     | 16
pan     | 16
tom     | 16
```

I know I can do it via sql but I was just wondering if I can do it with python too.

Answer (score 0):

Use `limit`, and you can apply `offset` for skipping records

```
sql_query="select first_name,age from random_table limit ? offset ?"
cur.execute(sql_query, n, offset)
```

Since you have the result as a list you can do this: `nested_tuple_list[:n]` it will give you first n elements.

Comment: First of all limit doesnt work like that limit just limits ur asnwers so if I said 2 i would get the first 2 items on my list,second of all I said I dont want to do it via sql query.

Comment: Since you have the result as a list you can do this: `nested_tuple_list[:n]` it will give you first n elements.